# overloading delete [] operator with throw in c++

Tags: c++

As per code it should execute catch block but why is it not executing

How to test for the else operator in overloaded delete operator

Thanks in advance

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void operator delete[](void *p) throw(int)
{
    if (p)
    {
        cout << "address of p is" << p << endl;
        free(p);
        cout << "in delete\n" << endl;

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "in throw \n";
        throw 5;
    }
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        int *a = new int[20];
        a = NULL;
        delete[] a;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "in catch" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: A delete expression on a null pointer, won't call the deallocation function

Comment: Works for me with VS2015 as release and debug and as 32bit and 64bit build. Both `in throw` and `in catch` are written to stdout.

Comment: Don't do it. § 6.7.4.2: "If a deallocation function terminates by throwing an exception, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: Yeah it work in windows but not in linux can you please tell me the reason simon

Comment: @ShekharSingh Throwing there is undefined, so a compiler may remove the entire `else` branch, or just ignore it, or anything else that it wants.

Answer (score -1):

The ***p** in operator overloaded function accepts an address.
Send an address when calling it by using **&** after **delete** statement. In this example...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void operator delete[](void *p = NULL) throw(int)
{
    if (p)
    {
        cout << "address of p is" << p << endl;
        free(p);
        cout << "in delete\n" << endl;

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "in throw \n";
        throw 5;
    }
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        int *a = new int[20];
        a = NULL;
        delete[] &a;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "in catch" << endl;
    }
}
```